# Can't use ctrl+shift+c to copy to secondary clipboard

Tags: debian, i3, clipboard, alacritty

Running I3 without a desktop environment on Debian 12.
My terminal is Alacritty and my shell is bash.

I am unable to copy into what I assume is the secondary selection clipboard using the default shortcut CTRL+SHIFT+C.

I can mark/highlight text by holding down left mouse button and dragging it and it is correctly copied into the primary clipboard which allows me to paste using middle mouse button.

If I copy something from for instance a browser using ctrl+c, I am able to paste it into the terminal using CTRL+SHIFT+V.

I have tried a different shell, for instance sh and zsh.

I have tried different terminal emulators, for instance Alacritty and i3-sensible-terminal.

I have tried to search for conflicting shortcuts using grep, I have been unable to find any conflicting shortcuts in X11, Alacritty, I3 config etc.

I have also tried using tmux without luck.

I have tried to set keybindings manually in the Alacritty config file without luck.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction to get my CTRL+SHIFT+C working properly?

Comment: Did you try using CTRL+ALT+C and CTRL+ALT+V instead ?

Comment: I did, without luck, it seems like it sends the CTRL+C signal when I also hold down ALT.